# bidirectional one-to-one not working with spring-data-jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have 3 tables in postgresql for which I have 3 spring data entities.
These are Parent, Child and Third tables with same names on the entity side as well.

Parent table has a column name col_p which has a foreign key relationship with the id field of child table.

I need a bi directional OneToOne relationship between the two. So I have created the entities as follows:

Parent Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="parent")
@NamedQuery(name = "Parent.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Parent p")
public class Parent implements Serializable {

     @OneToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "col_p")
     private Parent parent;
}
```

Child Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="child")
@NamedQuery(name="Child.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Child c")
public class Child implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="child")    
    private Parent parent;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="third_id")
    private Third third;
}
```

Using this entity definition, when I save parent using parent repository created with spring data jpa, it works fine. I can see a record in parent table.

Now, there is another entity called Third (as already mentioned in the beginning)  that has Child entity has one of it's attributes as follows:

Third entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="third")
@NamedQuery(name="Third.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM Third t")
public class Third implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="third")
    private List<Child> child;

}
```

The problem is that when I use spring data jpa to fetch entity named Third and expect it give me Parent entity from child entity (third --> child --> parent) , parent entity is always returned as null.
When I query the tables starting from the id that I am using in Third table and navigate from child to Parent, parent does have a corresponding record.

I am not what what exactly I have messed up with the relations in the entities that I have created that wouldn't fetch me a record for Parent entity.

Please help.

Comment: Your class Parent looks incomplete.

Comment: I have posted only the relevant portion of it. What’s seems to be missing to you ?